# PHP: Color a square depending id and getting data from db

Tags: php, html, css

I must to create a page filled by n square, these square will be coloured using a colorpicker, then when the data is stored on db I must to get these value and fill in the background color attribure:

I'm using this code:

```
<?php
    $square=0;
    $sqid=0;

    while ($square <= $numSquare) {

        $square++;
        $id = $sqid++;

        $getExist = $DB_CON -> query("SELECT * FROM square WHERE SQUARE = " . $id);
        $exist = $getExist->fetch();

        if (isset($exist[2])) { $color=$exist[2]; } else { $color=''; }

        if (null !== $exist) {
            if ($exist[0] = $id) {
                print '<div class="square" id="' . $exist[0] . '" style="background-color:' . $color . '"></div>';
            }
        } else {
            print '<div class="square" id="' . $id .'"></div>';
        }
    }
?>
```

So it search for the row in DB, (eg: row 1 contain color #000000) and put in `style="background-color:x"` attribute, the problem is that using this code all the square got the background-color set to none even if they mustn't have none. (eg = must to be `<div class="square" id="n">` and got `<div class="square" id="n" style="background-color:">` ), in addition to this the first square, related to the ID 0 in database doesn't got any color even if must to be #000000.

Thanks to all who can help.

Comment: well then the query fails, debug that. and running it in a loop like that is crazy

Comment: @Dagon you're right, I'm going to setup the error log, stay tuned

Comment: Never use "SELECT * FROM" with indiced result array, either name your table columns or use an associative array as result. You can't rely on the column position in a database (or strongly should not)

Comment: reading the log file I'm selecting all the columns, each query is 122 Query SELECT * FROM square WHERE ID = 0

Comment: do one! querry, and loop the results

Comment: @Dragon how i can do only one query?

Comment: `SELECT color FROM square`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You reset `$color` yourself:

```
if (isset($exist[1])) { $color=$exist[1]; } { $color=''; }
```

Here is an 'else' missing:

```
if (isset($exist[1])) {
    $color = $exist[1];
} else {
    $color='';
}
```

*Please see my comment about `SELECT *` and indiced query result - bad practise.*

**Update to question 2:**

The next two lines look weird, too:

```
    if (null !== $exist) {
```

Can $exist become `null`? Well, depends on your connection driver, but PDOStatement::fetch() returns `false`, a simple `if ($exist)` would be enough. It sould be better to put the other if/else color assignment inside this block.

And the next line is an **assignment**! This only gets false if $id is 0, which can't be as it is 1 in your first loop and gets bigger all the way.

```
        if ($exist[0] = $id) {
```

This looks useless as condition (as it is part of your WHERE-clause) and useless as assignment as well.

I usually use the fetch()-method inside an if or while condition. This is the main part I read from your code:

```
$getExist = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id, color FROM square WHERE square = ?');
for ($id = 0; $id < $numSquare; $i++) {
    $getExist->execute([$id]);
    $style = '';
    // 1. fetch row, and check if there is one
    // 2. check if a color is defined (if it is possible in db it is not)
    if ($exist = $getExist->fetch() && isset($exist[1])) {
        $style = 'background-color: '.$exist[1];
    }
    echo '<div class="square" id="'.$exist[0].'" style="'.$style.'"></div>';
}
```

Comment: now the problem that i got all the div with the attribute background color set, so the last else not working, regarding you comment about the SELECT i think we can leave out, since this project must only be a friend project and need to be executed one time only

Comment: PS: i've abbandoned the selecting of ID and using a SQUARE column so when i do the INSERT to save the color will select this and not the ID

Comment: @andreaem - If this answer solved **the problem you asked about**, please mark it as the correct answer, and ask a new problem if you are having new / other problems.

Comment: this not working, I must to take the values from the db, but if not found I must to write the blank squares and respect the html id, so I must to do the while cycle and then inside put your code?

Comment: I use for(), you use while() for other (not shown in code) reason. Just adobt the code from my last edit - the content of my for-loop is nearly the content of your while-loop. The prepare() has to be before the loop, everything else inside.

Comment: removing the while loop i got this error Notice: Undefined variable: exist in /home/ubuntu/workspace/index.1.php on line 44 Call Stack: 0.0010 236264 1. {main}() how i can get the array?

Comment: One of my "usual" problems with exist vs. exists.